# Https to http page - is the submitted information being passed securely?

Tags: security, jsp, forms, https

I have an https jsp page that takes login values (username/password) and validates the info and then sends the user to the appropriate page.

The `form action` attribute is set to go to a servlet under **http** like `http://www.mysite.com/go.validatelogin`

Since the login page is under **https**, can I be assured that the login values are being passed securely, even though I am going to the servlet under http?

I hope that makes sense. I just want to be sure that I'm still passing the data securely the way I have things setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You're passing data under http.

Comment: I had a bad feeling that that was the case:( I had a problem with the session invaliding itself, and I had to come up with a workaround to this. Now if I set the 'action' to https I'll be back to square one again...bummer. Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: @katura What problems are you having? Perhaps you should start a separate question for that...

Answer (score 2):

No, if the action URL is `http:`, the form data is sent over HTTP, in the clear.

In any case, all actions that require an authenticated user must be accessed through HTTPS. Logging in with HTTPS and then reverting to HTTP is a huge security flaw; hackers won't be able to log in later, but they can sniff the current session ID and perform actions as the user.

Comment: Thank you for providing additional information as to why it has to stay on https.